# How the variables of derived class are built when inheriting?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

When inheritance, do the variables in the base class get copied into the derived class? how the architecture of the child class would be?

```
{
public:
 int m_id;

 Base(int id=0)
     : m_id(id)
 {
 }

 int getId() const { return m_id; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
 double m_cost;

 Derived(double cost=0.0)
     : m_cost(cost)
 {
 }

 double getCost() const { return m_cost; }
};
```

does **m_id** get copied into derived while ******derived object's*** instantiation*** ?

Comment: Nothing gets "copied" anywhere. The base class is a part of the derived class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++: Construction and initialization order guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517050/c-construction-and-initialization-order-guarantees)

Comment: @underscore_d yes it's useful but I still did not get an appropriate answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The derived class (`Derived`) is not copying the base class (`Base`) in a strict sense. `Derived` is inheriting from `Base` therefore `Base` is part of `Derived`. Think of `Derived` extending `Base` with new methods and new members.

In your example, `Base` has a default constructor because the first parameter is an optional parameter (`Base(int id=0)`, you can call the constructor without any arguments to set `id` to `0`).

When you use inheritance, `Derived` must always call `Base`'s constructor in `Derived`'s constructor before doing anything else (to make sure `Base`'s variables are initialized). However, because `Base` has a default constructor, the compiler does so magic to make this optional.

If you want to call a specific `Base`'s constructor from `Derived`'s constructor you can do the following:

```cpp
Derived(double cost=0.0) : Base(1 /* or whatever you want it to be */)
{
  m_cost = cost;
}
```

Comment: so how the Derived class is stored in memory with the base portion? because while Derived object instantiation, if you try to print the address of object Base in its constructor (std::cout<<this), you would get the same address when printing the address of Derived object in its constructor !. Are they in the same memory? I can't get this idea..

Comment: @slahOmar They are _the same object_, so of course they have the same address. To simplifiy, the base members basically exist 'above' the derived members in memory, but they're part of the derived object.