# how to initialize base class with members of derived class

Tags: c++, initialization

Beginner here, my simplified code:

A.h

```
class A{
public:
  A(int x);
private:
  int _x;
}
```

A.cpp

```
A::A(int x) 
  : _x(x)
{
}
```

B.h

```
class B : public A{
public:
  B()
private:
  int _y = 1;
}
```

B.cpp

```
B::B()
  : A(1) //works
  : A(_y) //doesn't work
{
}
```

Why does the initialization with a member of B not work, but with a bare integer it does.
I mean I can just go for the working method but I'd like to know the cause.

Thanks for any helpers!:)

Comment: When the object of the base class is created then the members of the derived class is not yet created.

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: More general reference: [Construction and initialization order guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517050/)

Answer (score 1):

Vlad has given you the reason, here's a workaround that avoids the need to duplicate your magic number:

```
class B : public A{
public:
  B();
private:
  static const int initial_y = 1;
  int _y = initial_y;
};

B::B()
  : A(initial_y)
{
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1G67Eaye8Y58P28G)

Comment: Thanks! Why would I `int _y = initial_y`? Couldn't I just skip this step?

Comment: It depends on how you are using `_y`.  This code preserves the behavior of your original code by giving `_y` an initial value (if you omit `_y = initial_y` then `_y` will be *uninitialized*), while still giving you the ability to re-assign `_y` later, if you wanted to. But this way allows you to both initialize `A()` and `_y` with the same value, without having to define that value twice.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class's base classes are fully initialized *before* any of the derived class's data members are initialized.

In the case of:

```
class B : public A{
public:
  B();
private:
  int _y = 1;
}

B::B()
  : A(_y)
{
}
```

Data members that have initial values in their declarations are implicitly handled by the constructor's member initialization list.  So, in this case, the compiler treats the above code *as-if* you had written it like this instead:

```
class B : public A{
public:
  B();
private:
  int _y;
}

B::B()
  : A(_y), _y(1)
{
}
```

As you can see, `A(_y)` is called before `_y` is initialized, which is *undefined behavior*.